# Is this logically the same?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I tried doing this :

```
a = [1,2,3]
if 68 not in a:
    print 'missing'

a = [1,2,3]
if not 68 in a:
    print 'missing'
```

the output is the same. But I doubt it if the two are logically the same. Is this logically the same or not? Thanks

Comment: If you change `68` for `1` (or `2` or `3`) do they still output the same? Does that not resolve your doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are same. This is same as how them literally means.

Even the internal comparison cost are same, probably.